# Prompt not storing value as String

Tags: javascript, string, prompt

I'm working on an exercise but I'm not able to understand why my prompt is not being stored as a string and therefore can't be compared to my switch case

Any input returns false:

```js
function getColor(selection) {
  switch (selection) {
    case 'red':
      return true;
    case 'green':
      return true;
    case 'blue':
      return true;
    default:
      return false; //returns false because the user picked an unavailable color
  }
}

var colorname = prompt('What color do you want?');
var isAvailable = getColor(colorname);

if (getColor === true) {
  console.log('Good news! That color is available');
} else {
  console.log('We are sorry, that color is not available');
}
```

I noticed the input is not being stored as a String as I tried to `.toUpperCase` the "colorname" var and it won't change to Upper Case.

Comment: Strings are ***immutable***. You cannot change an existing string but can assign a new string to the same or another variable.

Comment: You have `if (getColor === true)`. Did you mean to have `if (isAvailable === true)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the result of `getColor(colorname)` in `isAvailable` variable and later instead of using that variable you are comparing the function name again.

change your if from `if (getColor === true)` to `if (isAvailable)` or `if (isAvailable === true)`

or one of these:

```
if(getColor(colorname) === true)

if(getColor(colorname))
```